# How get full path to file in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to delete file. I know relative path from public directory.
Is any zend-way methods to delete file?
I think define BASE_DIR in index.php is not right way.

Comment: please clarify what ZF has to do with it.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid declaring a BASE_DIR or ROOT_PATH constant in your index file?

Comment: Mike B - don't know) Now i using BASE_DIR. If no any default zend methods, i think nothing to do

Comment: We need more details, some sample code.

Comment: @Gordon I think the ZF tag tells us about the directory structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming directory structure like this:

```
/application/
/public/
  /files
    file1
```

path to `file1` is

```
$path = realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/files/file1')
```

then you may perform any string operations on this path
(e.g. check the length of your relative path and substract it from the ending of `$path`)

`APPLICATION_PATH` is already defined in `index.php` by `Zend_Application`.

Then you may delete the file using `unlink`.

It's just a guess. You didn't write how the file is stored.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that above is no longer the case in Zend Framework 2, where neither APPLICATION_PATH or ROOT_PATH exists! What is even more important to know, **they are no longer needed** because of this line in application entry point (index.php):

```
/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
```

So, when dealing with paths under ZF2 now remember that everything is relative to your /public folder.